# Can't update table in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to run this query to delete a row in guilds if ownerid doesn't exist in players id.

```
DELETE FROM guilds WHERE ownerid NOT IN (SELECT id FROM players);
```

But i get this error:
Can't update table 'players' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Also i tried with `NOT EXISTS` AND `LEFT JOIN` but i got same result.

What can i do in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you try to run this code in a trigger? Or do you have a trigger on guilds? You have to post the triggercode for guilds, the code that generates that error is there.

Comment: I realized it works perfectly using SELECT. So i'll have to delete all guilds without ownerid manually which isn't too much work, anyways thanks for trying to help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your query also deletes `players` table, actually deletes everything. Since `players` table is somehow protected, you get that error, you do not need to touch it, try this;

```
DELETE FROM guilds WHERE ownerid != ALL(SELECT id FROM players);
```